Import data from Excel and show to view through @ViewBag
I tried to import an Excel file to get a specific column data and show it to view, but there is nothing. I ran debug and it does get data, but not showing anything.
my HTML, js:
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Import_BaoHanh", "HangSp", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "uploadForm" }))
            {
            <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" class="file" value="Choose File From Your Computer">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add"/>
            <!-- Modal import Excel -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="importBH" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">               
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>MA_HANG</th>
                                        <th>DISCONTINUE </th>
                                        <th>BAO_HANH</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                               <tbody>                                 
                                   <tr ng-repeat="maHang in @ViewBag.MaHangList">
                                       <td>{{maHang}}</td>
                                       <td></td>
                                       <td></td>
                                   </tr>
                               </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#importBH"></button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#uploadForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Import_BaoHanh", "HangSp")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    // Update page content or handle server response
                    $('#importBH').modal('show');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle error
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
</script>

The Controller:
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Import_BaoHanh(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request != null)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase filetonkho = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
                    if ((filetonkho != null) && (filetonkho.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filetonkho.FileName))
                    {
                        string fileName = filetonkho.FileName;
                        string fileContentType = filetonkho.ContentType;
                        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[filetonkho.ContentLength];
                        var data = filetonkho.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(filetonkho.ContentLength));

                        // Set the license context based on your usage
                        // If you are using a commercial license
                        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;
                        // If you are using a non-commercial license
                        // ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

                        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(filetonkho.InputStream))
                        {
                            var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                            var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                            var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                            var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;

                            List<string> maHangList = new List<string>();

                            int columnIndex = -1;
                            for (int col = 1; col <= noOfCol; col++)
                            {
                                if (workSheet.Cells[1, col].Value?.ToString() == "MA_HANG")
                                {
                                    columnIndex = col;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (columnIndex != -1)
                            {
                                for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                                {
                                    string maHang = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, columnIndex].Value?.ToString();
                                    maHangList.Add(maHang);
                                }
                            }

                            ViewBag.MaHangList = maHangList;
                            return View("Index");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = " Đã xảy ra lỗi, Liên hệ ngay với admin. " + Environment.NewLine + " Thông tin chi tiết về lỗi:" + Environment.NewLine + Ex;
            }
            return View("Index");
        }

